# Dynamic DataGrid-esque solution for custom XML input

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, .net-core, wpf-controls

We are looking to replace a legacy data management app that saves into XML files with a modern code-base.
There are a lot of requirements set by the legacy app that DataGrid in WPF has been struggling to meet.

Such as: default values for a column where it has no data in the XML,
lookups into another file on specified columns with a modal window, the descriptor column a lookup uses,
and ordering of the columns.

The solution needs to be dynamic as each file has a different amount of headers in the Schema.

Could anyone help point me in the right direction for a solution.

I've been trying in WPF .Net Core C# with DataGrid but while I can display the data, I'm struggling to apply the schema order and modal lookups.

I've also been looking into creating a custom control but struggling to find good documentation on table based controls.

Here's an example of one of the XML data files:

```
<data>
  <id>file.name</id>
  <table name="" description="">
    <schema>
      <field name="id" type="int" localisation="" descriptor="false" default="0" lookup="" order="-1" doNotExport="false" />
      <field name="name" type="string" ...>
      ...
    </schema>
    <rows>
      <row>
        <name>item</name>
        <id>0</id>
        ...
      </row>
      ...
    </rows>
  </table>
</data>
```

Ideally don't want to change the structure of the XML at all

Want to have a grid output like DataGrid or Excel but with the features mentioned above.

Comment: The file posted you should be able to use DataSet.ReadXML(filename).  One you have a DataSet you can bind your WPF controls to the DataSet and not change the XML.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, I had tried that before but it looks like I was way over-complicating how I handled the Data

Comment: The ReadXml only works with simple xml like the one you posted.  Xml with many layers, the ReadXml method splits into fragmented tables that cannot be parsed.  So what didn't work in the past will work with the posted Xml.